# Restrict user access to intranet for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, security, intranet, restrict

I'm using an asp.net application, where I have a requirement to restrict users to download reports available in our application if he/she is trying to download report outside intranet. How to find whether the user is website from internet or intranet.

Comment: is site accessible from outside of intranet? do you want this authentication for one page or for entire application?

Comment: everything need to be accessible outside of intranet, just few reports are there which need to be restricted outside intranet, so if there is a way to find where the user is trying to access so that I can go ahead and implement that and restrict the download option

Comment: if you want to check user belongs to intranet or not . you should check that through LDAP class. if user does not belong to intranet then LDAP will return invalid user